# Swift Network.framework (websocket): read response headers set by the server

Tags: ios, swift, macos, websocket, network.framework

I’m trying to figure it out how a ws client can read additional headers set by the WebSocket server during the handshake.

Websocket Server (built using the `NWProtocolWebSocket`)

```
let wsOptions = NWProtocolWebSocket.Options()
wsOptions.setClientRequestHandler(serverQueue) { (_, headers) -> NWProtocolWebSocket.Response in
    let additionalHeaders = [("custom-header", "hi there")]
    return .init(status: .accept, subprotocol: nil, additionalHeaders: additionalHeaders)
}
```

Websocket Client (built using the `NWProtocolWebSocket`)

I'm aware that `NWProtocolWebSocket.Metadata` has an `additionalServerHeaders` but I don't know how to access it.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Did you get a chance to read the response header set by server?

Comment: Sadly no, it can only be done via C APIs (nw_ws_response_enumerate_additional_headers)

Comment: I am implementing the C APIs in swift project to establish a connection using nw_connection_t, can you share any snippets for retriving the headers from the server. I kind of struck up here for many days..

Comment: Headers can be retrieved by using nw_ws_response_enumerate_additional_headers

Comment: Hi I'm creating the connection with "let endpoint = nw_endpoint_create_url(socketUrl)" and adding custom headers like this "nw_ws_options_add_additional_header(ws, "Authorization", "Bearer ")" but when using this iam getting error "nw_protocol_copy_ws_definition_block_invoke [C1.1.1:1] nw_ws_validate_server_response " and the connection goes to WAITING  with error Optional(Software caused connection abort). do you have any idea on this, i need to pass multiple headers which are needed for the validation that i can't avoid